# How to show current selection QML TreeView?

Tags: qml

I can show current selection QML ListView but similar thing doesn't work in TreeView.

Part of the problem is for TreeView it doesn't recognize `index` which is passed to delegate in case of `ListView`. I tried `styleData.index`but that doesn't work either.

```
    rowDelegate: Item {
        id: row_delegate
        height: 40
        Rectangle {
            id: rectid
            anchors.fill: parent

            MouseArea {
                id: mouse_area
                anchors.fill: parent

                onClicked: {
                    console.log("Row clicked " + rectid.styleData.index)

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The output is:

> qml: Row clicked undefined

Comment: `styleData` is not attached to the `MouaeArea`, so your example is wrong and (fortunately) the answer is still valid. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#itemDelegate-prop), you have a set of properties within the namespace `styleData` that can be used for almost the same purposes from within a delegate.

As an example, you can set the text property of a label that is part of your delegate as it follows:

```
text: styleData.value
```

Where `styleData.value` is (documentation excerpt):

> the value or text for this item

Similarly, you have:

> styleData.pressed - true when the item is pressed
>
> styleData.index - the QModelIndex of the current item in the model
>
> styleData.hasChildren - true if the model index of the current item has or can have children

And so on... Please, refer to the documentation for the full list.

Be aware also of the note at the end of the documentation:

> **Note:** For performance reasons, created delegates can be recycled across multiple table rows. This implies that when you make use of implicit properties such as styleData.row or model, these values can change after the delegate has been constructed. This means that you should not assume that content is fixed whenComponent.onCompleted is called, but instead rely on bindings to such properties.

Comment: I updated the question, `styleData.index` doesn't really work in rowDelegate

Comment: I guess `styleData` is an attached property, so you cannot access it that way, it is not part of your `MouseArea`. Try giving you rectangle an *id*, then refer to `styleData` by means of that *id* as `rectId.styleData.andSoOn`.

Comment: still doesn't work, the error message is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined"

Comment: Please, post an updated snippet, otherwise I cannot know what you are trying to do this time and what's wrong.

Comment: I updated it and as you can see I gave id to all elements and tried all of them but same result.

Comment: No, wait, I said wrong, it is not an attached one that way. Let me start my laptop and try it... Otherwise try assigning the index to a property of the rectangle and access it.

Comment: I defined property for Rectangle `property int myindex : styleData.index` and access it but now it says its always 0.

Comment: nevermind, I tried styleData.row and that worked! However it doesn't quite solve my problem..how to make the treeview show/sset the current selection!?

Comment: Well, index is the current selected item, it makes sense for it to be 0 until you select something different!!

Comment: no for index, it always shows 0 for all items but styleData..row worked. But still how can I use that to set current index? Not quite there yet.

Comment: Set what? The question was - *Part of the problem is for TreeView it doesn't recognize index*. Now you know how to read the actual index of the delegate. Setting/changing the current index has nothing to do with that!!